# Como posso prevenir que um usuário envie várias vezes o mesmo form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um formulário em uma página, as vezes os usuários podem clicar duas vezes no botão para enviar o formulário...

O formulário é um

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(...))
{
}
```

Como eu posso evitar que isso aconteça?

Comment: O melhor seria você não ter problemas com isso acontecendo, pois, do contrário, fica possível _atacar_ seu site fazendo isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O jeito mais simples é, via JavaScript, detectar que o formulário foi enviado e desabilitar o botão de submit.

Exemplo (com jQuery):

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(botao) { $(botao).prop('disabled', true); });
```

Mas isso atende somente no lado do cliente. Para melhor usabilidade é melhor utilizar algo mais apropriado como, por exemplo, substituir um botão por um "carregando" ou algo do tipo. O exemplo é apenas um *quick fix*.

Se a questão não é meramente usabilidade, e sim a validade do formulário, você pode marcar sua action com o atributo [AntiForgeryToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.antiforgerytoken.aspx), que gerará uma chave específica para aquela requisição do formulário (e validada pelo próprio ASP.NET no submit).

Comment: O problema é o navegador estar com o js desabilitado.

Comment: @perdeu Por isso devemos garantir sempre a integridade dos dados na aplicação e não confiar no cliente. Quanto ao usuário, ao desabilitar o Javascript ele precisa compreender que vai ter um ***grande*** impacto na usabilidade. Por outro lado, isso está ficando menos comum. O Firefox, por exemplo, removeu na versão 23 ou 24 o campo de desabilitar JS e imagens da tela opções, pois eram funções muito pouco usadas.

Comment: Realmente um usuário normal sempre vai querer navegar com Javascript habilitado. O único problema são os mal intencionados que desabilitam o javascript propositalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Pode **prevenir** esta situação fazendo por exemplo isto:

```
<form onsubmit="if(typeof fSub !== 'undefined') return false; fSub = true;">
```

> **Nota**: *Pode declarar a variavel `fSub` globalmente para evitar a validação do tipo.*

De qualquer modo a validação tem **sempre** de ser feita do lado do servidor para evitar ataques.
É má prática fazer a validação só de um dos lados.